# Ler um arquivo JSON e imprimir os dados em formato tabular

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

O arquivo é "grades.json", cuja estrutura é:

```
    {"students": [{"name": "Alan", "lastname": "Silva", "exam1": 50, "exam2": 80, "exam3": 91},
    {"name": "Paula", "lastname": "Souza", "exam1": 95, "exam2": 98, "exam3": 99}]
    }
```

Objetivo: Ler o arquivo  "grades.json" e mostrar os dados em formato tabular, incluindo uma coluna adicional com a média de cada estudante a direita das notas dos exames e uma linha adicional com a média da turma em cada exame.

Eu tentei usar o pandas mas não consigo fazer nada além de ler o JSON:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dt = pd.read_json("grades.json")
print(dt)
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como os dados em seu *JSON* são semi-estruturados, ou seja formato não é compatível com os formatos retornados pelo método [`DataFrame.to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html), o indicado é criar o `DataFrame` com a função [`pandas.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) que é usada para normalizar dados semiestruturados.

Para calcular a média use a função [`numpy.average()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.2/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) e ao criar uma nova coluna no `DataFrame` a aplique utilizando o método [`DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) que aplica uma função em um dos eixos do `DataFrame`, no caso aplicando por linha usando as colunas como valor.

```
import json # Necessário para decodificar o JSON
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Abre o arquivo grades.json
with open('grades.json') as grades:    
  dados = json.load(grades) #Decodifica os dados

#Normaliza os dados contidos na chave students
dt = pd.json_normalize(dados,'students') 
#Cria uma nova coluna e calcula a média dos três exames
dt['média'] = dt.apply(lambda x: np.average([x['exam1'], x['exam2'] , x['exam3']]) , axis=1)

print(dt)
```

Resultando:

```
    name lastname  exam1  exam2  exam3      média
0   Alan    Silva     50     80     91  73.666667
1  Paula    Souza     95     98     99  97.333333
```

Funcionando no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/CoordinatedSparseProcedures

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com semi-estruturado?

Comment: Está escrito na primeira linha da resposta:  **"Como os dados em seu JSON são semi-estruturados, ou seja formato não é compatível com os formatos retornados pelo método DataFrame.to_json(),"**

Comment: @ Augusto Vasques   consegue me ajudar em ?   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443657/extraindo-as-palavras-de-um-texto-longo-e-criando-estat%c3%adsticas-das-mesmas-o-que