# Extraindo as palavras de um texto longo e criando estatísticas das mesmas. O que está errado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, texto

Temos o livro "*Pride and Prejudice by Jane Austen*" do projeto **Gutenberg**:

http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1342

O objetivo é extrair **todas** as palavras do texto, criando estatísticas como:
frequência de cada palavra, total de caracteres no texto, tamanho médio da palavra, tamanho médio de frase e um "top 10" das palavras mais longas.

Observando o texto, verifiquei que muitas palavras contêm caracteres estranhos como:

```
"the,"
```

Exigindo que se removam inicialmente estes caracteres.

Como eu tentei fazer:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from string import punctuation
from collections import Counter
with open("1342-0.txt",encoding='utf8') as f:
    texto = f.read()

words = texto.split()
n_words =[]
for word in words:
    for p in punctuation:
        if p in word:
            n_word = word.replace(p,"")
            n_words.append(n_word)
        n_words.append(word)
```

"1342-0.txt" é o livro em questão.
O código acima tenta eliminar os caracteres indesejados mas não funciona. O que está errado?
Alguma ideia melhor?

Comment: Não entendi o que tem de estranho em `"the,"`. É a virgula? Se for é só remover toda pontuação antes de processar o texto.

Comment: @Augusto Vasques: isso q estou tentando! Remover pontuacao, acentos... mas nao funcionou –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma ideia inicial é fazer o *split* não só por espaços, mas por qualquer caractere que não faça parte de uma palavra:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

r = re.compile(r'\W+')
c = Counter()
with open("1342-0.txt", encoding='utf8') as f:
    for linha in f:
        for word in r.split(linha):
            c.update([word])

print(c)
```

O atalho `\W` é "tudo que **não** for letra, número, ou o caractere `_`"  - e como no texto tem "palavras" como `_she_`, isso é considerado uma palavra diferente de `she`. Eu também considero que os números (como `1`) são "palavras", que também são contabilizadas.

Conforme encontro as palavras, vou atualizando o `Counter` usando método [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) (se a chave não existir, ela é criada com o valor 1, e caso ela exista, soma-se 1 ao seu valor - no final temos a contagem total de cada palavra).

Outro detalhe é que `read()` carrega todo o conteúdo do arquivo para a memória, de uma vez. Dependendo do tamanho do arquivo, isso pode ser um problema. Já o código acima lê uma linha por vez (e estou assumindo que não existe um caso de uma palavra começar em uma linha e terminar em outra - se bem que neste caso, usar `read` e `split` também não iria considerar que é a mesma palavra).

Se você não quiser incluir o `_` como parte de uma palavra, basta mudar a regex para:

```
r = re.compile(r'[\W_]+')
```

---

O problema é que também há palavras com hífen, como `over-scrupulous`. O código acima considera que são duas palavras diferentes ("over" e "scrupulous"). Se quer que elas sejam uma palavra só, tem que mudar um pouco:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

r = re.compile(r'\b\w+(?:-\w+)*\b')
c = Counter()
with open("1342-0.txt", encoding='utf8') as f:
    for linha in f:
        for word in r.findall(linha):
            c.update([word])

print(c)
```

Agora eu uso `\w+` (um ou mais caracteres que formam uma palavra), e coloco um trecho contendo hífen e `\w+` (e todo este trecho pode se repetir zero ou mais vezes). Assim pego palavras com um ou mais hífens também.

Se não quiser incluir o `_` como parte de uma palavra, use:

```
r = re.compile(r'\b[^\W_]+(?:-[^\W_]+)*\b')
```

---

Vale lembrar que [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) só considera os caracteres `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_{|}` ``. Se tiver qualquer outro caractere no texto que não seja letra, número ou `_`, ele não será removido.

Um exemplo é o caractere `“` (presente no texto), que **não** é a mesma coisa que `"` (são aspas diferentes, o primeiro é o ["LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) e o segundo é ["QUOTATION MARK"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm), e se você usar `punctuation`, só removerá o segundo).

Comment: Obrigado! GOstaria de entender o que estou fazendo de errado na hora de tirar os caracteres indesejados das palavras. Alguma ideia?

Comment: @LaurindaSouza Não entendi bem sua lógica, mas parece ser porque vc faz `n_word = word.replace(p,"")` (ou seja, a palavra sem a pontuação fica em `n_word`, mas no final vc faz `n_words.append(word)` (ou seja, adiciona a palavra original, com as pontuações). Ficou um algoritmo meio confuso, e acho até que tem `append` a mais, uma versão mais simples do seu loop seria: https://ideone.com/LnJf3v

Comment: se puder ajudar   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443768/utilizando-recursos-de-programa%c3%a3o-funcional-para-remover-uma-lista-de-palavras-d

Answer (score 2):

Para remover os caracteres de pontuação de um texto em python basta só uma linha:

```
from string import punctuation

texto = '''It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single man in
      possession of a good fortune, must be in want of a wife.

      However little known the feelings or views of such a man may be
      on his first entering a neighbourhood, this truth is so well
      fixed in the minds of the surrounding families, that he is
      considered the rightful property of some one or other of their
      daughters.      
'''

#Remove os pontuadores
print(texto.translate(str.maketrans('', '', punctuation)))
```

Resultando:

```
  It is a truth universally acknowledged that a single man in
  possession of a good fortune must be in want of a wife

  However little known the feelings or views of such a man may be
  on his first entering a neighbourhood this truth is so well
  fixed in the minds of the surrounding families that he is
  considered the rightful property of some one or other of their
  daughters
```

Funcionando no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/DarkcyanPointlessChord

Exemplo 2: https://repl.it/repls/ResponsibleVariableTheories

A lógica é a seguinte, o método [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) retorna uma cópia da string na qual cada caractere foi mapeado através da tabela de conversão especificada pelo método [str.maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans).

Comment: Não conhecia este translate!

Comment: Não queria deixar como resposta porque quase não dá conteúdo de tão simples. Eu ia deixar como comentário na sua pergunta.

Comment: @LaurindaSouza O problema é que `punctuation` só considera alguns caracteres ASCII, mas no texto tem por exemplo o caractere `“`, que **não** é a mesma coisa que `"` (o primeiro não é removido se usar `punctuation`, somente o segundo é).

Comment: @hkotsubo é só adicionar o caractere `“` na tabela tradução. Não tem mistério.

Comment: Sim, Augusto, é que aí ela vai ter que saber todos os caracteres não-ASCII que tem no texto e incluí-los na lista. Dependendo do texto, pode ser mais trabalhoso...

Comment: @Augusto Vasques: terei que utilizar str.maketrans('', '', punctuation) para cada caracter? Não entendi bem... Aqui só está removendo as vírgulas...

Comment: @LaurindaSouza ele tirou tudo que está definido em [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#string.punctuation). O que estamos discutindo é sobre o caractere `“` que não está definido em `punctuactor` e eu disse que é só concatenar o caractere `“` a `string.punctuation` para que seja também removido.\

Comment: @Augusto Vasques: entendi! Sou iniciante na Programação! Obrigado!

Comment: @LaurindaSouza olha esse outro exemplo https://repl.it/repls/ResponsibleVariableTheories que remove os caracteres `“` e `”` .É sobre isso que estávamos discutindo, que caso queira remover algo que não esteja definido em  `string.punctuation` faz-se necessário adicionar e eu defendo que a adição é simples.

Comment: @LaurindaSouza A adição é simples se vc sabe quais caracteres estão presentes no texto. Mas se surgir um texto novo com um caractere não previsto, terá que mudar o código e adicioná-lo também. Já a minha resposta não tem esse problema, já elimina tudo que não é parte de uma palavra - tudo bem que tem outros problemas, como o fato de usar regex, que não é lá tão simples e nem tão performático :-)

Comment: @Augusto Vasques Por que chamar str.maketrans e nao texto.maketrans ?

Comment: @LaurindaSouza Leia na documentação que [str.maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) é um método estático e métodos estáticos devem ser chamados pela classe e não por instâncias.

Comment: @LaurindaSouza Já o [str.translate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) é um método de instancia o que significa que deverá ser evocado por uma instância `texto.translate(...`.